# creating a nested dictionary using map

Tags: python, json, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have the following variables:

```
LANGUAGES = ['EN','DE','FR','NL']

STOPWORDS_EN = [1,2,3,4]
STOPWORDS_DE = [5,6,7,8]
STOPWORDS_FR = [9,10,11,12]                
STOPWORDS_NL = [13,14,15,16]
STOPWORDS = [STOPWORDS_EN, STOPWORDS_DE,STOPWORDS_FR, STOPWORDS_NL]

ARTICLES_EN = ['the','a']
ARTICLES_DE = ['der', 'die', 'das']
ARTICLES_FR = ['le', 'la', 'les', 'las']
ARTICLES_NL = ['het','die']
ARTICLES = [ARTICLES_EN, ARTICLES_DE,ARTICLES_FR,ARTICLES_NL]
```

Attempt 1:

```
{lang: {'stopwords':sw, 'articles':art} for lang in LANGUAGES for sw in STOPWORDS for art in ARTICLES}
```

Attempt 2:

```
{lang: {'stopwords':STOPWORDS[i], 'articles':ARTICLES[i]} for lang in LANGUAGES for i in range(4)}
```

How to proceed without loops, i.e. with a one liner?

Desired output:

```
{'EN': {'stopwords': [1,2,3,4], 'articles': ['het', 'die']},
 'DE': {'stopwords': [5,6,7,8], 'articles': ['the','a']},
 'FR': {'stopwords': [9,10,11,12], 'articles': ['le', 'la', 'les', 'las']},
 'NL': {'stopwords': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'articles': ['het', 'die']}}
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [enumerate()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate):

```
{lang: {'stopwords': STOPWORDS[i], 'articles': ARTICLES[i]} for i, lang in enumerate(LANGUAGES)}

{'EN': {'stopwords': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'articles': ['the', 'a']},
 'DE': {'stopwords': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'articles': ['der', 'die', 'das']},
 'FR': {'stopwords': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'articles': ['le', 'la', 'les', 'las']},
 'NL': {'stopwords': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'articles': ['het', 'die']}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip()` as:

```
{ lan: {'stopwords': stop, 'articles': art } for lan, stop, art in zip(LANGUAGES, STOPWORDS, ARTICLES)}
```